# What is the difference between node.js https request and XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

What is the difference between a HTTPS request sent via node.js module and via XMLHttpRequest?

I am trying to send a HTTPS GET request to amazon aws to get a security token from javascript (XMLHttpRequest) and it always fails with "Origin http://my_ip is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin", but if I send same HTTPS GET request via a node.js module it works fine.

I am confused of this because if server does support CORS, any request from any where should fail, but it goes through via node.js, but not via XMLHttpRequest.

**This FAILS**

```
var url_ = "https://sts.amazonaws.com/?Action=GetSessionToken" +
            "&DurationSeconds=3600" +
            "&AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" +
            "&Version=2011-06-15" +
            "&Timestamp=" + encode(timestamp) +
            "&Signature=" + encode(hash) +
            "&SignatureVersion=2&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256";

// Simple GET request
$.get(url_, function(data) {
    alert("response: " + data);
});
```

**This WORKS**

```
var https = require('https');
var options = {
    host    : 'sts.amazonaws.com',
    method  : 'GET',
    path    : '/?Action=GetSessionToken' +
              '&DurationSeconds=3600' +
              '&AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' +
              '&Version=2011-06-15' +
              '&' + timestamp +
              '&' + signature +
              '&SignatureVersion=2&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256'
};

https.get(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(d) {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });    
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Can anyone explain me how this works?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The browser is constrained by the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). Node.js is not.

That is, a browser will let scripts make HTTP requests via XHR only to sites in the same domain as that of the page that loaded the script. Node.js, however, will allow HTTP requests to any domain.

(The browser story is slightly more involved now with CORS, but it's still the basic issue here.)

*edit* — to elaborate, now that I've re-read your question: CORS is a cooperative protocol.  A server on the Internet will serve content to anybody, generally; that's the whole point of running a web server. CORS has nothing to do with HTTP requests unless the requestor *asks* about it. If you have URL "http://x.y.z/something", and you type that into your browser's address bar, then the browser will unhesitatingly issue the HTTP request to that site.  The Same Origin Policy (and CORS) only comes into play when some *code* in a page from a site in another domain (not "x.y.z") attempts to run an HTTP request via XHR.  In that case, the browser asks the "x.y.z" site about access; the default answer is "no", but that's the *browser* imposing that rule, not the server.

Comment: Specifically (to extend the answer and encourage discussion to make this a canonical answer) the point of SOP is to prevent malicious code from being loaded in your browser, to prevent say ... some website running a tracking ad on your computer, where the ad loads a bit of javascript that shows an image (so you don't know you "got infected" because you see the image) and then that code monitors every keystroke you enter onto a page and refers it to its home server. Say it monitors for bookmarks (can be done in JS) and sees what bank you're on? CC Numbers anyone?

Answer (score 2):

It is difference in environment. You can usually freely send any HTTP request anywhere (just as you're doing right now by sending request to this very site).

Node.js executes on your behalf program provided by you and thus, presumably, trusted. That's why there's no restrictions by default. You **can add** arbitrary restrictions if you expect to include and run untrusted code - just check your favorite search engine for "Node.js untrusted code" for some idea on sandboxing available.

Browser, on the other hand, almost always run untrusted code, but on behalf of user and with all his possible permissions. Since browser's environment must be standartized for all browsers to work in same way, a set of security policies was agreed upon between authors and they implemented in their browsers control of XHR connections outgoing from JavaScript according to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and later, [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). **Browser itself controls those limitations** and not JavaScript or remote server. You'll have exactly same restrictions imposed by environment if you chose another language as well.

Answer (score 1):

node.js is a server side language. Donot be confused by the .js extension. That always causes a hell lot of confusion when you're new to it. So its a lot like php, or C++. YOu can send whatever request wherever you want. Access any site(the https request hence). But in Browser javascript, this is a client side language. Browser won't allow you to access a page from another server. Say you are at host.com:80. You can only acess data from host.com:80/*not host2.com or even something.host.com

This ddoesn't apply to node.js